# Including two window.matchMedia into script

Tags: javascript, jquery, media-queries, gsap

I am trying to add this:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)"), window.matchMedia("(max-height: 479px)");
```

into my existing script right now which only has:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)");
```

When I add the second `.matchMedia` mentioned above, the script doesn't fire at all.

I've tried adding two variables:

```
var mqls = [ 
  window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)"),
  window.matchMedia("(max-height: 479px)")
];

function mediaqueryresponse(mql){
  document.getElementById("match1").innerHTML = mqls[0].matches // width: 480px media match?
  document.getElementById("match2").innerHTML = mqls[1].matches // width: 479px media match?
}
```

Here is the script working before adding `max-height`: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w1xnsgcg/)**. Please note that the script is at the bottom of js panel. The top script is for **TweenMax** to animate the lines.

And here is the script with the added variables: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dar_T/spkga15t/2/)**.

Comment: There's a console error in your second fiddle.

Comment: @Blazemonger Console error? Like there are syntax errors in the script?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but shouldn't simply adding an `and` in between the queries would serve you the purpose, so that it becomes: `var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 479px) and (max-height: 480px)');`? I am of course assuming that you want the `smallBlock()` animation to run when `min-width` is `479px` _and_ `max-height` is `480px`. Let me know if my assumption is right.

Comment: @TahirAhmed Ah. Sorry for the confusion. No. I'd like the `smallBlock()` animation to run when `min-width` is `479px` OR `max-height` is `480px`.

Comment: @user2252219: a comma `,` should do then. posted an answer. let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `smallBlock()` animation to run when `min-width` is `479px` *or* `min-height` is `480px` then I think adding a comma `,` in between the queries should do the trick.

Take a look at **[this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpmbtjju/1/)** and test it out if it produces the result you are looking for.

***JavaScript:***

```
var mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 479px), (max-height: 480px)');
function smallBlock() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;
        TweenLite.set('.square', { visibility: 'visible' });
        var tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.fromTo('.l1', 2, { height: 0 }, { height: 27 });
        tl.fromTo('.l2', 3, { width: 0, }, { width: 45 });
        tl.fromTo('.l3', 2, { height: 0 }, { height: 27 });
        tl.fromTo('.l4', 3, { width: 0 }, { width: 45 });
        tl.timeScale(4);
    }, 600);
};
function largeBlock() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;
        TweenLite.set('.square', { visibility: 'visible' });
        var tl = new TimelineLite();
        tl.fromTo('.l1', 2, { height: 0 }, { height: 227 });
        tl.fromTo('.l2', 3, { width: 0, }, { width: 445 });
        tl.fromTo('.l3', 2, { height: 0 }, { height: 227 });
        tl.fromTo('.l4', 3, { width: 0 }, { width: 445 });
        tl.timeScale(4);
    }, 600);
}
function handleScreen(mql) {
    mql.matches ? smallBlock() : largeBlock();
}
mql.addListener(handleScreen);
handleScreen(mql);
```

Hope this helps. Documentation on CSS media queries can be found **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)**.